# Rails 4.2.4 in production mode in coffeescript could not catch page load event, turbolinks disabled, how to do it in Production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, production-environment

in development-environment - work 1,3,4,5 cases
in Production-environment - no one !

how can i get it on production ?

settings of my project below :

coffeescript

```
$ ->
  alert('->')

$(document).on "page:change", ->
  alert('page:change')

jQuery ->
  alert('jQuery ->')

$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  alert('ready page:load')

$(document).on 'ready', ->
  alert('ready')
```

gems

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3.0'
gem 'uikit-sass-rails'
gem 'normalize-rails'
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require uikit
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command mostly your assets are not yet compiled on production environment

rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV = production